# how to get src/url from <iframe> using java

Tags: java, html

```
 String str = " <iframe width=\"640\" height=\"360\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/UMUeWqnwmjs\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
```

How to take the Src from this tag?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In such simple case you can use regexp (normally you should not use it for parsing html). The code below will look for src and retrieve it:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("src=\"([^\"]+)\"").matcher(str);
matcher.find();
String src = matcher.group(1);
```

`src` will contain your src from iframe.